# Should np.linalg.norm be squared when implementing k-means clustering algorithm?

Tags: python, k-means

The k-means clustering algorithm objective is to find:

[image: a]

I looked at several implementations of it in python, and in some of them the norm is not squared.

For example (taken from [here](https://johnloeber.com/docs/kmeans.html)):

```
def form_clusters(labelled_data, unlabelled_centroids):
    """
    given some data and centroids for the data, allocate each
    datapoint to its closest centroid. This forms clusters.
    """
    # enumerate because centroids are arrays which are unhashable
    centroids_indices = range(len(unlabelled_centroids))

    # initialize an empty list for each centroid. The list will
    # contain all the datapoints that are closer to that centroid
    # than to any other. That list is the cluster of that centroid.
    clusters = {c: [] for c in centroids_indices}

    for (label,Xi) in labelled_data:
        # for each datapoint, pick the closest centroid.
        smallest_distance = float("inf")
        for cj_index in centroids_indices:
            cj = unlabelled_centroids[cj_index]
            distance = np.linalg.norm(Xi - cj)
            if distance < smallest_distance:
                closest_centroid_index = cj_index
                smallest_distance = distance
        # allocate that datapoint to the cluster of that centroid.
        clusters[closest_centroid_index].append((label,Xi))
    return clusters.values()
```

And to give the contrary, expected, implementation (taken from [here](https://imaddabbura.github.io/post/kmeans_clustering/); this is just the distance calculation):

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import norm

def compute_distance(self, X, centroids):
        distance = np.zeros((X.shape[0], self.n_clusters))
        for k in range(self.n_clusters):
            row_norm = norm(X - centroids[k, :], axis=1)
            distance[:, k] = np.square(row_norm)
        return distance
```

Now, I know there are several ways to calculate the norm\distance, but I looked only at implementations that used `np.linalg.norm` with `ord=None` or `ord=2`, and as I said, in some of them the norm is not squared, yet they cluster correctly.

Why?

Comment: Specify `ord=2` for L2 norm

Comment: @coldspeed, not sure I get you. As I mention at the end of the question, I looked only at implementations that used `np.linalg.norm` with `ord=None` or `ord=2`.

Comment: Ah, didn't see that bit.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81481/why-does-k-means-clustering-algorithm-use-only-euclidean-distance-metric

Answer (score 0):

By experience, to use the norm or the squared norm as the objective function of an optimization algorithm yields to similar results. The minimum value of the objetive function will change, but the parameters obtained will be the same. I always guessed that the inner product generates a quadratic function and the root of that product only changed the magnitude but not the objetive function topology. A more detailed answer can be found in here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2253443/difference-between-least-squares-and-minimum-norm-solution
Hope it helps.